# Multiple VSCode Debuggers In Parallel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

**Short Version:** Can VS code debugging extensions for different languages run in parallel and pass control to eachother? (Such that you can call one language's code from another, and have the debugging extensions step out from one language, into another, in a fluid debugging experience).

**Long Version:** I wrote a custom programming language which I can initiate method execution in by sending RPC commands from another language (like C#). On the backend, I support breakpoints/callstack, and all the nice debugging goodies for the VM which runs this custom language. Because calls are initiated from C#, and the backend for the custom programming language already supports debugging, would it be possible to make a Visual Studio Code extension which allows me to step from C# code, directly into my custom programming language code?

I'm well aware I can make an extension which handles sole debugging for just my language, and create debugger extensions just for that language alone. But I would really prefer if I can make a test framework in C# that initiates calls to another language's code and have it trigger document opening, line highlighting, callstack updating, breakpoints, etc (when RPC calls from C# happen) for that other language.

**Side Note**: It's a question of whether an IDE supports certain functionality I need, and thus, it isn't going to get any more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anser is no. You can only start one debug adaptor at a given time.

Comment: Thank you so much! Greatly appreciate it.